# Single address table for company, company_branch, users

Tags: mysql

I'm a database noob and i'm asking this simple question because i found no answer to my question. I'm using MySQL.
I have 3 tables Company, Company Branches, Users and these 3 tables have similar fields like address. So i want to store address information of company, company branch and user in a separate table "address_information". 
Can i achieve this? 
[image: question reference image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this.
[image]

The tool used to data modeling is [SQL Developer Data Modeler](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/datamodeler.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `Addresses` table would have an `id` for the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Each of the other 3 tables would have an `address_id` column that could be used to `JOIN` to `Addresses.id` to get to the address.

That's a "1:many" relationship.  '1' address for each of many 'users', except that you don't necessarily have multiple users with the same address.

Comment: So address table will be the parent table? And we need to create address first and then assign it to either one of those 3 tables? Is that right?

Comment: @Khuzema - That sounds like what I would do.